# Derivations of algebras graded by a group

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-graded-algebras, graded-rings-modules, derivations

Let $A$ be an algebra. A **derivation** of $A$ is a linear map $d:A \rightarrow A$ such that $d(ab)=d(a)b + a d(b)$ for $a, b \in A$.

If $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded algebra, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.  Then a **derivation** is usually defined as a linear map $d:A \rightarrow A$ such that $d(ab)=d(a)b+ (-1)^{|a|}ad(b)$.

Now if $A$ is a $G$-graded algebra, where $G$ is a group. That means $A= \oplus_{g \in G} A_g$ and $A _{g_1} A_{g_2} \subseteq A_{g_1g_2}$. Is there any research or definition of the derivation of $A$?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $d(ab) = d(a) b + (-1)^{|a|} a d(b)$?

Comment: @ cgodfrey I prefer to that form, but what does $|a|$ mean here?  I want to know whether there is a definition of $d$.

Comment: See Bourbaki, _Algèbre_ III.10 for a rather general treatment of such derivations.

Comment: The definition of derivation in the graded case is mistaken: $a$ should be assumed homogeneous, and possibly there are further requirements. The setting in any case is clumsy since it mixes several incompatible conventions: derivations, graded derivations, graded super-derivations... Omitting the word "super" is possibly fine when one has a single setting in mind, but when one wants to generalize it is really the way to make the setting obscure.